# Name of object in string - how to use it

Tags: groovy

I'm trying to find a way to print text from an object that name is in another string in Groovy.

Here is a simple example:

```
def object1 = "some text"
def object2 = "object1"
println(object2)
```

It gives me `object1`. How to modify the third line to get output as `some text`?

Comment: In what environment do you plan to run this? Is this for some DSL? Or does your environment (assuming it's not just plain groovy) not allow to pass around proper data structures?

Comment: This seems like an X-Y problem, but there's [`Eval`](https://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/api/groovy/util/Eval.html).

Comment: First I want to make it work in plain groovy @cfrick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `binding` script properties:

```
def object1 = "some text" 
def object2 = "object1" 
binding.setProperty('object1', object1)
println(evaluate(object2))
```

Comment: What binding is doing? It works with binding line commented out also.

Comment: I was testing on `groovyconsole.appspot.com` so without the binding it didn't work. Maybe in your runtime it's already accessible. The `binding` makes the variables accessible through the script object as properties. `evaluate` runs the code that is in the string, so not super safe for external strings :)

Comment: Thx for the explanation. It works in the groovy console program but not in Jenkins. After adding binding in Jenkins works also.